# Deployments to with Terraform Cloud via GitHub actions suddenly failing with "Invalid workspaces configuration"

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-cloud

I use the `TF_WORKSPACE` environment variable in combination with tags to allow me to use the same Terraform code with multiple Terraform Cloud Workspaces.

```
$env:TF_WORKSPACE="name-of-workspace"
terraform -chdir=deploy/bucket init
```

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "My-Org"

    workspaces {
      tags = [
        "payment-service",
        "infrastructure",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This has been working fine up until about a week ago, and now I am getting the following error in GitHub Actions.

```
Run terraform -chdir=deploy/bucket init
  terraform -chdir=deploy/bucket init
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    TF_WORKSPACE: payment-service-infrastructure-dev
    TF-DIRECTORY: deploy/bucket
    TERRAFORM_CLI_PATH: /home/runner/work/_temp/976ebbc9-6810-4e00-b2e9-aec8919f4485
/home/runner/work/_temp/976ebbc9-6810-4e00-b2e9-aec8919f4485/terraform-bin -chdir=deploy/bucket init

Initializing Terraform Cloud...
Initializing modules...
Downloading app.terraform.io/My-Org/lambda-deploy-bucket/aws 0.1.0 for app_bucket...
- app_bucket in .terraform/modules/app_bucket
╷
│ Error: Invalid workspaces configuration
│ 
│   on main.tf line 7, in terraform:
│    7:   cloud {
│ 
│ Only one of workspace "tags" or "name" is allowed.
│ 
│ The 'workspaces' block configures how Terraform CLI maps its workspaces for
│ this single
│ configuration to workspaces within a Terraform Cloud organization. Two
│ strategies are available:
│ 
│ tags - A set of tags used to select remote Terraform Cloud
│ workspaces to be used for this single
│ configuration. New workspaces will automatically be tagged with these tag
│ values. Generally, this
│ is the primary and recommended strategy to use.  This option conflicts with
│ "name".
│ 
│ name - The name of a single Terraform Cloud workspace to be
│ used with this configuration.
│ When configured, only the specified workspace can be used. This option
│ conflicts with "tags".
╵

Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
```

This **MUST** be down to some change in either Terraform Cloud or GitHub actions as I cannot seem to replicate it locally. Also, I can take a previous Action run that worked and if I rerun it I get this error.

I am really stuck and would appreciate some pointers as to what to do.

Comment: This error is a bug in Terraform v1.6.0. You can avoid it either by downgrading to the latest v1.5.x patch release or by upgrading to Terraform v1.6.1 where the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a [known issue with version 1.60](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/34046#issuecomment-1755904468) of Terraform.

I was not pinning my version with the `hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2` GitHub Action. So the solution is to pin to a different working version:-

```yaml
steps:
- uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
  with:
    terraform_version: <desired>.<version>.<number>
```